# flutter app shows just a white screen when running

Tags: firebase, flutter

[image: THE IMAGE]I just finished linking my Flutter app with Firebase, the problem is that when I run the app there's only a white screen in the emulator, I tried to know why but it just takes me to 'web_entrypoint.dart' file as you can see in the image. What exactly is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: consider adding code rather than the screen shot of code

Comment: Run a `flutter clean`and `flutter pub get`, it should normalize, the cause is the launch of the firebase plugin that doesn't find the default instance.

Comment: You must have missed something from the set up, have followed all of the instructions on your firebase package?
You could also try their example project to see if this runs

Comment: @Calaom yes I have followed all the instructions, and I did try their example project

Comment: @KTJ Can you maybe share your code or any error you get (if you get some)?

Comment: @Chance Still doesn't work

Comment: If you noticed the debug mode is pausing the application at the place of the problem, press play on the vscode debug panel, stacktrace will print to the console the error that is happening, take the error and put in your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Don't run it with Chrome when you are dealing with firebase. Use an emulator.